# Testing for difference between count data where there are missing values (i.e. 0 in some cells)

Tags: nonparametric, dataset, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test

I have collected data on different bumblebee species visiting a particular species of flowers over the course of the day. Counts were made every 10 minutes for 6 hours. I have now put all of my data into a spreadsheet with 4 columns (Species A, Species B, Species C, and Species D), with the counts of each species below in rows that correspond with the time that I recorded them. For example, Species A was recorded 3 times between 10:30 and 10:40, and Species B was recorded once in that time period. Species C and D were not recorded between 10:30 and 10:40.

I want to be able to undertake a test that tests for a significant difference in the total abundance of species visiting the flowers (which I have decided is initially a Kruskal-Wallis and then a Mann Whitney-U). When I put all of the data in a spreadsheet to use for analysis I am left with various blank cells (in the example above is would be Species C and D between 10:30 and 10:40). If I wanted to undertake a Kruskal-Wallis test and then a Mann Whitney-U should I change the blank cells to have 0 values to indicate that those particular species were not recorded in that time frame? Or shall I leave them blank?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to do whatever your software interprets as a zero.

Comment: Hi mdewey, thanks for the response. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that. Apologies, I am fairly new to statistics and trying to get my head around it all has been a challenge in itself. Do you mind elaborating please?

Comment: If your software interprets blanks as zero then leave them blank. If it interprets them as missing then change them to zero. If it does something else then act appropriately. I am assuming these are genuine zeros, they could have had a value but they do not, as distinct from structural zeroes which could never have happened (pregnancies in men, and so on)